# Error - incompatible DacFx version is installed

Tags: .net

I am new in MVC 4 using visual studio 2012. It created default Connection. I want to "open table definition" of Table in "Server Explorer" (right click on table > Open Table Definition ). But it throws error in Dialog box with message "an incompatible DacFx version is installed". What Should I do?

Something need to install/upgrade using NuGet?

Comment: Have you tried [this solution](http://carlupq.wordpress.com/2013/07/07/solutions-to-two-microsoft-visual-studio-2012-errors-1-this-version-of-sql-server-data-tools-is-not-compatible-with-the-database-runtime-components-installed-on-this-computer-an-incompatible-dacfx/)?

Answer (score 4):

You most likely need to upgrade the Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools the the latest version. The download should upgrade the DacFX component as well, you'll find the October 2013 version here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027

Answer (score 1):

You can see this problem also when trying to add a table to a database in the Server Explorer in Visual Studio.
Also if you right click on proprieties you get : 'Incompatible versions of SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) and database runtime components are installed on this computer' , with a link to SSDT.

So the solution is to install SQL Server Data Tools in Visual Studio 2012
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/jj650015